# mongodb как хранить данные

Tags: mongodb

В общем есть у меня пользователь у которого есть поля которые могут меняться (аватар, имя). Так же у меня есть посты и комментарии, которые должны обладать ссылкой на пользователя(автора). Выборка постов будет очень часто выполнятся. На ум мне приходит, лишь одно: хранить дубликат пользователя для комментариев и постов, но это не оптимально, так как при обновлении данных о пользователе их придется менять во всех постах и комментариях. Существует ли какое то стандартное решение такой задачи? Какое решение организации является правильным?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вариант 1**, как в БД:
Коллекции:

- пользователь `users {_id, nickname, ...}`
- посты `posts { _id, author_id, text, ts }`
- комментарии `comments {_id, post_id, ts, text  }`

`NoSQL` - это вообще не база, а класс хранилищ данных, которые не относятся к традиционным `SQL` базам данных. Так, что из предложенных тобой вариантов остается только два: `SQLite` и `MongoDb`.

Хочу заметить, что мы можем использовать `user_id = _id`, что даст прирост в выборке данных по первичному ключу.

`post.id = posts_id` , можно использовать как ссылку, так и просто тип `int`

**Вариант 2**,
 объединяем `post` и `comment`. Храним структуру `post`:

```
{ author_id, text , count, comments [ user_id, ts, text ] }
```

Хранить ни каких дубликатов не надо... Можно вполне обновлять конкретный элемент массива.

Comment: а как будет выглядеть выборка всех постов со всеми комментариями и их авторами?

Comment: а зачем всех постов со всеми комментариями?
хотя это проще, чем кажется: mongo_find({ },{},n, l) ... n кол-во постов, l - аналог TOP в MySQL
отдаст данные всей коллекции

Comment: Рассматривая второй вариант, учитывайте ограничение размера BSON-документа в 16Mb. Этого предела сложно достигнуть, но всё же

Comment: переформулирую вопрос. Можно ли монго выбирать все forenkey? Что то вроде: 
users{_id, nickname, password, avatar, full_name}
posts{_id, author_id, text, comments: [comment_id]}
comment{_id, author_id, text, post_id}

могу ли я выбрать за один запрос к монго все посты, которые бы сразу содержали данные о авторе, комментариях и их авторах.

Comment: нет, в MongoDB на JOIN, нужен JOIN коллекций - используй RMDB
но как вариант - можно написать хранимую процедуру, которая раелизует эту функциональность. Но лучше ее не делать :)